# Improve speed on joining multiple images

Tags: python-imaging-library

What I'm trying to do is take numerous(up to 48) 1024x768 images that are color coded images(weather maps, the precip overlay) and add up the precip to fall over the course of time.  When I run into non-precip I want to take a box 5x5 around the pixel in question and average the value and use that value as the value of the pixel in question.

I can do this but it takes a long time to accomplish it.  I have heard numpy could improve the speed but I still haven't been able to wrap my mind around how it going to improve the speed given the sequence of events that have to take place.  It seems like I would still have to do it pixel by pixel.  I've included an idea of the code I'm using to accomplish this SLOWLY.

I have this actually as two separate program, one to download the images and the other does the image processing(working up toward merging the two programs in the near future, just trying to get all the bugs worked out before the merger.)  Hence some of the download coding may look a little strange.  I figure I could probably write the file straight to a variable but I haven't been doing it that way so I stuck with a bit longer approach.

Is there anyway of increasing the speed?  I don't see anyway of avoiding pixel by pixel due to the color coding scheme in place(look at the color bar in the lower left it shows the full color scheme...I only included part of it for demo purposes in the coding below.)  Some of the coding may be a bit rough since I chopped from the two programs and put the important parts in here...it shows what I'm currently doing and gives the full idea of how I'm going about doing it.

Also, if you happen to see this three to four or more days after it was posted you would need to change the date in the download link to the current date.  The files are only kept on the server for 3-4 days before they are removed.

```
from PIL import Image
import time
import urllib
import os

pathstr = '/'
url = 'http://mag.ncep.noaa.gov/GemPakTier/MagGemPakImages/gfs/20140216/00/gfs_namer_006_1000_500_thick.gif'
urllib.urlretrieve(url,str(pathstr + '20140216006.gif'))

url = 'http://mag.ncep.noaa.gov/GemPakTier/MagGemPakImages/gfs/20140216/00/gfs_namer_012_1000_500_thick.gif'
urllib.urlretrieve(url,str(pathstr + '20140216012.gif'))

url = 'http://mag.ncep.noaa.gov/GemPakTier/MagGemPakImages/gfs/20140216/00/gfs_namer_018_1000_500_thick.gif'
urllib.urlretrieve(url,str(pathstr + '20140216018.gif'))

url = 'http://mag.ncep.noaa.gov/GemPakTier/MagGemPakImages/gfs/20140216/00/gfs_namer_024_1000_500_thick.gif'
urllib.urlretrieve(url,str(pathstr + '20140216024.gif'))

class Convert():
    def __init__(self):
        self.colorscale2 = [(255,255,255),(127,255,0),(0,205,0),(145,44,238),(16,78,139),
                        (30,144,255),(0,178,238),(0,238,238),(137,104,205),(0,139,0),
                        (139,0,139),(139,0,0),(205,0,0),(238,64,0),(255,127,0),(205,133,0),
                        (255,215,0),(238,238,0),(255,255,0),(139,71,38),(255,0,0),(0,0,255),(0,0,0)]

        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0 
        self.grid = 0
        self.moist = 0
        self.scan = 0
        self.turn = 0
        self.precip = {}
        start = time.time()
        for i in range(6, 30, 6):
            if i < 10:
                filename = '/2014021600' + str(i) + '.gif'
            else:
                filename = '/201402160' + str(i) + '.gif'
            self.im1 = Image.open(filename).convert('RGB')
            self.image = self.im1.getdata()
            self.size = width, height = self.im1.size
            self.coordinates = self.x,self.y = width, height
            self.getprecip()
            self.turn = 1
        print (time.time()-start)

def getprecip(self):
    for self.x in range(81, 950):
        for self.y in range(29, 749):
            if self.turn == 0:
                self.moist = 0
            else:
                self.moist = self.precip[self.x,self.y]
            self.coordinates = self.x,self.y
            self.scan = 0
            self.imagescan()
            if self.turn == 0:
                self.precip[self.x,self.y] = self.moist
            else:
                self.precip[self.x,self.y] += self.moist


def imagescan(self):
    if self.image[(self.y * 1024) + self.x] == self.colorscale2[0]:
        self.moist =0
        self.grid -=1
    elif self.image[(self.y * 1024) + self.x] == self.colorscale2[1]:
        self.moist =.01
    elif self.image[(self.y * 1024) + self.x] == self.colorscale2[2]:
        self.moist =.1
    elif self.image[(self.y * 1024) + self.x] == self.colorscale2[3]:
        self.moist =.25
    elif self.image[(self.y * 1024) + self.x] == self.colorscale2[4]:
        self.moist =.5
    #on and on through self.colorscale2[18]

    if self.scan == 1:
        self.grid += 1
    if self.scan == 0:
        x = self.x
        y = self.y
        self.deliso540()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

def deliso540(self):
    self.grid = 1
    self.scan = 1
    for p in range(self.x-2,self.x+2):
        for q in range(self.y-2,self.y+2):
            self.x = p
            self.y = q
            self.imagescan()

    self.moist = self.moist / self.grid
```

Comment: is that a averaging filter? also known as mean filter? normalized box filter etc? which is used for image blurring.

Comment: No.  This is changing the value of the pixels from color to the underlying value of what the pixel represents and then adding up the values over a series of maps and then taking that total and turning it back into a color and plotting the color on the screen.  The 5x5 block is an averaging feature but it only occurs when the underlying pixel doesn't have a color that matches one of the colors that is being searched for.  It takes the 5x5 average and uses that value to represent the pixel in question.